# Al crear Virtual Host con xampp Apache no enciende

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, php7, xampp

Acabo de instalar xampp y quiero crear una ruta virtual para un proyecto pero al hacerla Apache no enciende pero cuando comento la ruta virtual Apache enciende.

**Archivo Hosts**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Archivo vhosts.conf:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Cuando el VirtualHost esta activado:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Cuando el VirtualHost esta comentado:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Alguien sabe porque pasa esto y como puedo solucionarlo?**

Comment: intenta quitando el virtual host con nombre localhost, ya que por defecto utiliza esos datos.

Comment: Hola, ¿Podrias añadir vhosts.conf escrito en vez de en una imagen por favor?

Comment: Buenas. ya puede arreglarlo era lo que dijo @DarkFrostnight pero no comprendo porque si antes yo lo usaba así